# Streamwriter writes but gives web exception

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, streamwriter, system.net.webexception

I am trying to insert data via web service. The code below writes to the database; however, I have an error (see bottom). What goes wrong here? and how to fix it?

```
//Create the web request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

//Set type to POST
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/XML";

// Write data  
using (StreamWriter postStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
     postStream.WriteLine("<biz_in><phone_no>+1604333333</phone_no></biz_in>");
     postStream.Dispose();
}
```

### Error:

System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message="The request was aborted: The request was canceled."
  Source="System"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:/Program Files/Program.cs:line 62
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 1):

StreamWriter closes the underlying stream when you dispose it.

Comment: Streamwriter proves to be much trouble than it should be. I've chosen to use just "Stream" instead as such

Stream postData = request.GetRequestStream();
postData.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
postData.Close();

However, I found another problem. The code above runs well in Console application. Since this is intended to be a mobile win 5 application, execution on my mobile ph gives another error. 

Error: An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource

What do you recommend?
assembly containing it cannot be found

Comment: Sry, error msg should be:

An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource
assembly containing it cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

You might want to increase the timeOut of the request.

I had the same issue where I was trying to upload 26Mb file in chunks, and it was failing with same error. I increased the timeout and it successfully posted it. (I was dealing with Amazon).

Answer (score 0):

Include this:

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
```

This will work, but will probably imply a performance penalty as there won't be any re-use (also known as HTTP pipelining) of TCP connections. TCP connections are now closed immediately and reopened on each HTTP-request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been instructed to set the MIME type to text/XML; I would presume your server is expecting valid XML to be sent in the body of the message.

The content you have in your example, namely this line:

```
postStream.WriteLine("+1604333333");
```

... will not qualify as valid XML data.

Try sending a valid XML document and see what happens from there. Here is a minimal document you can send. You should receive a different error as a result of sending this.

```
postStream.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><test />");
```